# newtonsoft. json serializeObject string contains fraction value doesn't seem to escape properly

Tags: json, sql-server, json.net, jsonconvert

Having an issue where my object is being serialized using Newton where one of the properties is a string that contains values that are fractions such as **1/2"**, **1/4"**, etc...

After serializing I'm passing the variable to a SQL Server Stored Procedure that is using **OPENJSON**.

The double quote in the fraction value doesn't seem to be escaping properly as it fails as invalid format for JSON.  When debugging I see below which would appear the " in the fraction value is not being escaped properly.

A little new to some of the serialization so could use a little help.

```
string strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myobject);



DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = '{"Number":64260,"Notes":"1/2\\" testing"}';
SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$')
    WITH(
        [Number] int   '$.Number'
        ,[Notes] nvarchar(max)   '$.Notes'
    ) AS myDat
Msg 13609, Level 16, State 4, Line 2 JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 't' is found at position 32.
```

If I remove the second "\" from the fraction value it works fine.

```
 public partial class TblEcr
{


    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

}
```

```
    public JsonResult OnPostUpdate([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, TblEcr ecr)
    {
        _context.TblEcr.Where(x => x.Number == ecr.Number).Select(x => ecr);
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string ecrJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ecr);

                var param = new SqlParameter[] {
                    new SqlParameter() {
                        ParameterName = "@json",
                        SqlDbType =  System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,
                        Size = 8000,
                        Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
                        Value = ecrJson
                    },
                    new SqlParameter() {
                        ParameterName = "@Status",
                        SqlDbType =  System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit,
                        Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output
                        //,Value = 10
                    },
                    new SqlParameter() {
                        ParameterName = "@ErrorDetails",
                        SqlDbType =  System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,
                        Size =8000,
                        Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
                    }};
                int affectedRows = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("dbo.usp_UpdateECR @json, @Status, @ErrorDetails out", param);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new JsonResult(ex.Message);
        }

        return new JsonResult(new[] { ecr }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

Comment: Could you add enough C# code to your question to generate that string as the result of a JSON.NET serialization?

Comment: Updated question.  Let me know if this is enough.  The stored procedure contains the SQL statement used in the example

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't repro for me.

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp8
{
    class Program
    {
        public partial class TblEcr
        {
            public int Number { get; set; }
            public string Notes { get; set; }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ecr = new TblEcr() { Number = 1, Notes = @"1/2"" testing" };

            string ecrJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ecr);
            Console.WriteLine(ecrJson);

        }
    }
}
```

outputs

```
{"Number":1,"Notes":"1/2\" testing"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for looking at it.

After putting more thought in to it, I simplified a record I was attempting to update and found my issue.  It is the stored procedure in SQL Server.

There was a string manipulation in the procedure that was causing the issue.  Basically a simple replace for another purpose.

```
Set @json = REPLACE(@json,'\"','"'); -- BOOM, this caused it.
```

Comment: Glad you found the problem.  Doing a Replace on a JSON string is always a red flag for causing these kinds of issues.